# Add View Source Code Button

Tags: javascript, html, quill

Is there any way to add view source code button to quilljs editor?

I looked into the documentation and no explanation for this or should be developed by the developer.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't extensively looked at the api but I think you are best off rolling your own button. It seems quill.js allows you to add your own custom toolbars to the documentation. I would look at this page to do that. http://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/

You can add an on click on the button that simply gets the editor's html and puts it in an element using this. `var html = editor.getHTML();` http://quilljs.com/docs/api/#quillprototypegethtml

Sorry to be brief, but if you need more info on how you can comment below.